# Show a field in "Layout View" and prevention on showing in "Design View"

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

How can I show a field in "Layout View" (Form and Report) and prevention on showing in "Design View" into VBA Access 2010 ?

Any idea is thankful :)

Comment: The Design view by definition shows all controls. Otherwise how would you change their properties? If your users go into Design view, something is wrong. Maybe give them an .accde?

Comment: Actually I need a code (or several codes) by VBA (Access 2010) for visible or invisible some of fildes for two position:
"Layout View" and "Design View" ,,
OR a trike:
a code for "Send to Back" and "Bring to Front" a field or object by VBA depended to situations:
"Send to Back" for "Layout View" and "Bring to Front" for "Design View"